# How do I change the moving average types in my Pinescript code?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm currently using two separate DEMA's as part of my rule system for the arrow plots on the chart for the indicator. I want to change the first DEMA input to a 20 EMA, and I want to change the second DEMA input to a 20 smoothing factor of the 20 EMA. How would I change that in my code?

I've been messing with the code but don't want to change much since it may mess it up too much and won't be able to find my way back to the original structure. I had someone else create this code and I'm trying to change it myself, since I can't hire him again.